# Warning: Given image is not CTkImage but {type(image)}. Image can not be scaled on HighDPI displays, use CTkImage instead.\n")

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

I am planning to make a currency converter a my final project for our course. But I have this problem where the image does not appear in the application

Code:

```
import customtkinter
from tkinter import *
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
from PIL import Image, ImageTk  # Import the Image module from PIL

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.config(bg="#202630")
app.geometry("400x450")
app.title("Currency Converter")

# Load the image using PIL
img_path = "money.png"
img_pil = Image.open(img_path)

# Convert the PIL Image to Tkinter PhotoImage
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_pil)

photo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, fg_color="#202630", image=img)
photo_label.place(x=0, y=0)

app.iconphoto(False, img)
app.mainloop()
```

I've tried converting the PIL image to tkinter image but it still does not show

Comment: Have you tried to do what the error suggests, and use a `CTkImage` rather than a `ImageTk.PhotoImage`?

Answer (score 0):

You should do what warning message suggests - use `CTkImage`

```
ctk_img = customtkinter.CTkImage(img_pil, size=img_pil.size)

photo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, image=ctk_img)
```

It needs to set size manually because it uses `(30, 30)` as default value.

---

But it seems you still need `Pillow` for icon

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_pil)
app.iconphoto(False, img)
```

---

Full working code which I used for tests:

```
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

app = customtkinter.CTk()

img_path = "money.png"
img_pil = Image.open(img_path)

ctk_img = customtkinter.CTkImage(img_pil, size=img_pil.size)
photo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, image=ctk_img)
photo_label.pack()

#img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ctk_img.cget('light_image'))
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_pil)
app.iconphoto(False, img)

app.mainloop()
```

---

Doc: [CTkImage](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkImage)